# Get element by ID is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Verry simple question:

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="test" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 300px;">
    Some text
</div>
```

And this JS in a seperate .js file:

```
$('#test').hover(function(){
    alert('it's working');
});
```

I get no errors from Fire Bug and I googled a lot on this.
Please help: Why is my code not working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Proabaly because you're running your javascript before the page has fully loaded. Move your script from the `<head>` to the bottom of your `<body>`

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You need to use double quotes in your alert or escape that apostrophe. Probably not the issue but it will cause a problem.

Comment: This is a very broad question - however, here are some questions to help you debug - Have you included a link to jquery source in the html page? Have you included a link to this js file in the html page? Have you wrapped your jquery code under a DOM ready handler ( document.ready ) ?and lastly, Do you see the nested `'` in the alert (Though this code might not be executed) ?

Comment: THAT'S IT! I moved my script link to the end of the body and it works!

Comment: Moving your code to the end of the file will work, but the more standard way to approach this, particularly in jQuery, would be to programmatically wait until the DOM is loaded to execute your even handling code.  See the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait until the DOM is loaded, otherwise, your javascript will run before `#test` even exists.  You can do that by wrapping your code in a `ready` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#test').hover(function(){
        alert("it's working");
    });
};
```

This is a tricky problem that can easily go unnoticed, because you won't actually get an error from jQuery by operating on an empty selection.

Alternatively, you could simply move your script to the bottom of the page, so that it executes after the rest of the DOM loads, but my preference would be to approach it this way.

Comment: The original question is written using jQuery

Comment: Really spender, that's just taking it too far. He clearly uses jQuery or jQlite or something along those lines

Comment: @spender : the `$()` function in the question is most probably from jQuery.

Comment: It certainly seems like a fair assumption that he is using jQuery in his JS code

Comment: .ready() parses when the page has been loaded completely. If you have the jQuery call the dom element prior to that file being initialized, it will return with nothing because jQuery has yet to be loaded.

It's like calling a function essentially, define, declare.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is most likely the " ' " you have in your alert message, it produces an error.

Try removing it.

```
$('#test').hover(function(){
    alert('its working'); 
});
```

Or else, have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7a4ts46s/

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#test').hover(function(){
        alert('it\'s working');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You got ' in the alert message - 'it's working' (the second ' closes the string unintentionally)
you should change in to

```
$('#test').hover(function(){
    alert("it's working");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the separate .js file is linked from the html file. If you put it at the bottom, it should work:

```
<script src="your-file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or link it in the  section and wait for the DOM is loaded, like the other answer says. Often, I like to put my .js file `<script>` tags at the bottom AND wait for the DOM to load.

Make sure that the .js file is loaded though, if it isn't linked from the html page, it will never run. General debugging tip: always make sure you're actually running the file you think you're running :)